# Compiling Qwt with Microsoft VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qwt

How do I compile Qwt with Microsoft Visual Studio?

NO information is available on the internet and even worse, documentation of Qwt is really limited.

Comment: by "Linking" you mean compiling Qwt with VS?

Comment: What do you mean by "link"?

Comment: @Saqlain Yes I mean, compile Qwt with VS.

Comment: @JBentley please see my answer above that one.

Comment: There is build documentation available [here](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/qwtinstall.html). Which step is causing you trouble?

Comment: What is causing me problem is the debug stuff that I have to fix it in a .pro file according to the documentation to install the Qwt.

Comment: I compile Qwt 6 under visual studio 2008 to 2012. I did make a few minor changes however these were in the qwtconfig.pri and these were only to change the naming of the libs / dlls. I am confused what exactly is the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use QTCreator, its a descent IDE (http://qt-project.org/wiki/Category:Tools::QtCreator)

```
Open QtCreator.
Open project... -> C:\Program Files\Qwt\qwt.pro
Build and Run
```

How it sounds?

This thread http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Offtopic/thread/22fa086f-1d37-4b95-8c06-f4441a73f8fa shows some issues while compiling qwt with VS, not sure if they are still present in latest VS versions or not.